# Generate prerelease script error

Tags: ros, script

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to run a local prerelease using the prerelease command generator website.
In my case it generates the following command:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/prerelease_job
cd /tmp/prerelease_job
generate_prerelease_script.py \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/master/index.yaml \
  jade default ubuntu trusty amd64 \
  heatmap \
  --level 1 \
  --output-dir ./
```

When I run the commands I get the following error message:

```
Fetching buildfarm configuration...
Fetching rosdistro cache...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/generate_prerelease_script.py", line 263, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/generate_prerelease_script.py", line 149, in main
    source_repository.name = 'prerelease'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What's the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216435/generate-prerelease-script-error/) by [DKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21308/dks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a bug, please open a ticket here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/issues

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21308/dks/) on 2015-08-25**:
Thank you, [ticket](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/issues/97) opened!